# Django CMS - how to detect if homepage?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

How can I detect in the template, if the current site is set as the homepage?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [is_home](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/models/pagemodel.py#L81).

```
{{current_page.is_home}}
```

Comment: Note that if you want to access this in the menu template you have to do:
{{ child.attr.is_home }}

Comment: We really could use some documentation on this besides the source code.

Comment: What if I want to check that in a view or in context_processor?

Comment: In my base.html template the page is `self`, but `self.is_home`does not work

Comment: I have tried the options here, it did not work. I just added an item to the context of the home page. context['it_is_home'] = True. Then I check {% if it_is_home %}.